# Cannot ouput string service via ROS_INFO

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a service of type string, my server simply responds with a string. I am trying to implement my client to simply call the service and ROS_INFO out the response. However, when I try to compile I get an error on the line where I am doing the ROS_INFO output. The error is:

**error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘struct std::basic_string’ through ‘...’**

*Here is my code:*

parallax_eddie_robot::get_version srv;

if(get_version_client_.call(srv))

{

ROS_INFO("%s",srv.response.version);

}

I don't know why it thinks my service is returning a struct because my service file (myservice.srv) is only for a string. It looks like this:

--

string version

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49042/cannot-ouput-string-service-via-ros_info/) by [kbedolla](https://answers.ros.org/users/3639/kbedolla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-11-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a nutshell, changing your print to `ROS_INFO("%s", srv.response.version.c_str())` should fix your compile error.

A string type in a ROS message/service maps to a std::string in C++ (see the [msg](http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg) package for more details). std::string's are not printable with something like printf, unless you get access to the underlying const char* data which is what printf's "%s" format string is expecting. You can get access to the C-string via the c_str() member on std::string.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kbedolla](https://answers.ros.org/users/3639/kbedolla/) on 2012-11-24**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-26**:
You can also use the C++ stream interface if you like: `ROS_INFO_STREAM(srv.response.version)`